# Bash + MySQL -d backtick issue

Tags: mysql, bash

I am helping to create a solution for a community project to monitor river levels for free, in the community spirit. The eventual product of this effort will be a system that takes data from a river level probe, and generates a graph for an online community.

I am early on with the project, and as I am familiar with Bash am using this to take a text file from the probe containing the data and push it into a MySQL database. All has been going really nicely until I hit a stumbling block. A number of my database table columns are numbers and so to interact with these using the MySQL command line tool backticks have to be used. Unfortunately I want to take the output from a MySQL statement and put it into a variable, but I think due to the two sets of back ticks MySQL is not getting the right command.

I have fudged it with a nasty work around like so which works all be it inefficiently:

```
mysql -N -D $targetDatabase -e "select \`"$timeSample"\` from RiverDataDays where date="$dateOfFile";" >tmpValue

dbEntry=`cat tmpValue`

echo $dbEntry
```

But actually, what I want to do is push it straight into an variable like this:

```
dbEntry=`mysql -N -D $targetDatabase -e "select \`"$timeSample"\` from RiverDataDays where date="$dateOfFile";"`

echo $dbEntry
```

Comment: One backslash before the backticks within the quotes doesn't work? And you should not escape the first backtick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
dbEntry="$(printf "SELECT \140%s\140 FROM 'RiverDataDays' WHERE date = '%s';\n" "$timeSample" "$(<tmpValue )" | mysql -N -D "$targetDatabase")"
echo "$dbEntry"
```

or

```
dbEntry="$(printf "SELECT \`%s\` FROM 'RiverDataDays' WHERE date = '%s';\n" "$timeSample" "$(<tmpValue )" | mysql -N -D "$targetDatabase")"
echo "$dbEntry"
```

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is **easier to nest**. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

---

```
\140
```

is the octal representation of a backtick, see

```
man ascii
```

Comment: Sputnick - thank you very much :) Being honest your syntax has lost me a little (I'm flagging today!), but reading the article made it clear about the problems using back ticks. By encompassing the above statement in $( ) has sorted my problem as I believe the syntax is expanded and executed inside the $().

Comment: I think you certainly pointed me in the right direction - the actual answer was this:-

Comment: dbEntry=$(mysql -N -D $targetDatabase -e "select \`"$timeSample"\` from RiverDataDays where date="$dateOfFile";")

Comment: Thank you again for your time and effort - thank you kind sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Followed Sputnick's link:-
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

And then revised code accordingly

dbEntry=$(mysql -N -D $targetDatabase -e "select \`"$timeSample"\` from RiverDataDays where date="$dateOfFile";")

echo $dbEntry

Brilliant forum - thank you very much :)