# import comma separated string from pipe to mysql db

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, sed

i need to insert following comma Separated String coming from stdout (speedtest-cli) into a mysql db

```
1746,Vodafone DE,Frankfurt,2017-04-24T16:00:13.708464,292.1655728839447,267.019,119047915.27025849,12007236.796291795
```

Column descriptions are:
SERVER_ID,SPONSOR,SERVER_NAME,TIMESTAMP,DISTANCE,PING,DOWNLOAD,UPLOAD

What is the best way to get this done without the need to save the data to csv and then importing it into mysql?

I'm able to convert comma separated  data to sqlable data

```
SQL_RESULT_DATA=$(echo $RESULT_DATA | sed -e "s/,/','/g;s/^\(.*\)$/'\1'/")
```

but

```
mysql --host=10.8.0.18 --user speedtest --password=speedtest < echo "INSERT INTO `TEST_DATA` (`SERVER_ID`, `SPONSOR`, `SERVER_NAME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DISTANCE`, `PING`, `DOWNLOAD`, `UPLOAD`) VALUES ( $SQL_RESULT_DATA )"
```

fails with

```
-bash: TEST_DATA: command not found
-bash: SERVER_ID: command not found
-bash: SPONSOR: command not found
-bash: SERVER_NAME: command not found
-bash: TIMESTAMP: command not found
-bash: DISTANCE: command not found
-bash: PING: command not found
-bash: DOWNLOAD: command not found
-bash: UPLOAD: command not found
-bash: echo: No such file or directory
```

table description:

```
MySQL [speedtest]> DESCRIBE TEST_DATA
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| TEST_ID     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| SERVER_ID   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SPONSOR     | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SERVER_NAME | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TIMESTAMP   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DISTANCE    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PING        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DOWNLOAD    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UPLOAD      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: at least show the respective field names of the implied mysql table

Comment: Is it possible for a field to contain a comma, with the field surrounded in quotes to protect it? That makes parsing it in a shell script much harder.

Comment: The MySQL documentation on `LOAD DATA INFILE` shows how to use a named pipe to avoid having to save CSV data into a real file.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain your errors on your test string,

```
mysql --host=10.8.0.18 --user speedtest --password=speedtest < echo
```

means "read stdin from file named `echo`"

`"` "begin another `mysql` argument as string, spaces are included in this argument"

```
INSERT INTO `TEST_DATA`
```

"execute command `TEST_DATA` and insert it's output in this string"

```
(`SERVER_ID`, `SPONSOR`, `SERVER_NAME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DISTANCE`, `PING`, `DOWNLOAD`, `UPLOAD`) VALUES ( $SQL_RESULT_DATA )"
```

contains same error as above, since back ticks are used to spawn subshell an get it's result

What you want to use is `-e` argument of mysql command to pass a query, and inside that query you need to escape backticks, as something like

`` mysql --host=10.8.0.18 --user speedtest --password=speedtest -e "INSERT INTO \`TEST_DATA\` (\`SERVER_ID\`, \`SPONSOR\`, \`SERVER_NAME\`, \`TIMESTAMP\`, \`DISTANCE\`, \`PING\`, \`DOWNLOAD\`, \`UPLOAD\`) VALUES ( $SQL_RESULT_DATA )" ``

See also:

- [Bash + MySQL -d backtick issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003367/bash-mysql-d-backtick-issue) for other backtick options
- https://explainshell.com/ for explanation of shell commands that you are troubleshooting.

Make sure to quote SQL_RESULT_DATA expression like this

```
SQL_RESULT_DATA="$(echo $RESULT_DATA | sed -e "s/,/','/g;s/^\(.*\)$/'\1'/")"
```

since otherwise it may lead to nasty globbing and word splitting issues in future, that can possibly lead to security problems, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells